# How do I get the only the first 3 digits of a number?

Tags: c++, vector, time, floating-point, precision

I have a vector of numbers (floats), representing everything after the second of some time stamp. They have varying lengths. It looks something like this:

4456

485926

346

...

Representing 0.4456, 0.485926, and 0.346 seconds, respectively. I need to convert each of these to milliseconds, however I can’t simply multiply each by some constant since they’re all of different lengths. I’m fine with loosing accuracy, I just need the first 3 digits (the millisecond bit). How can this be done?

Comment: Convert the number to a string then trim off anything after the first 3 digits

Comment: How do you represent numbers less than 0.1 (i.e., fractions with a leading 0 like 0.03)?

Comment: If you have the representations of the numbers in seconds form (eg 0.4456, 0.485926, and 0.346 seconds), then you could just multiply them by 1000, cast to int and get what you want. If for some strange reason you dont, then follow @PaulBaxter's suggestion

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: you would have to ensure all values were scaled correctly when creating the input values. Then you would get `700 -> 0.7`, `70 -> 0.07`, `7 -> 0.007`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that the *integral* portion of the float represents a subsecond value, so that `1234f` is actually `0.1234` seconds. That seems to be what your question states.

If that's the case, it seems to me you can just continuously divide the value by ten until you get something less than one. Then multiply it by one thousand and round. That would go something like:

```
#include <iostream>

int millis(float value) {
    if (value < 0) return -millis(-value);
    //while (value >= 1000f) value /= 1000f;
    while (value >= 1.0f) value /= 10.f;
    return static_cast<int>(value * 1000 + .5f);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        float f= atof(argv[i]);
        std::cout << "   " << f << " -> " << millis(f) << "\n";
    }
}
```

I've also put in a special case to handle negative number and a (commented-out, optional) optimisation to more quickly get down to sub-one for larger numbers.

A transcript follows with your example values:

```
pax> ./testprog 4456 485926 346
   4456 -> 446
   485926 -> 486
   346 -> 346
```

---

If instead the values are already sub-second floats and you just want the number of milli-seconds, you do the same thing but without the initial divisions:

```
int millis(float value) {
    if (value < 0) return -millis(-value);
    return static_cast<int>(value * 1000 + .5f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int getFirstThreeDigits(int number){
    return stoi(to_string(number).substr(0,3));
}

int main()
{
  float values[] = {4456, 485926, 346};
  int arrLength = (sizeof(values)/sizeof(*values));
  for( int i = 0 ; i < arrLength ; i++){
      cout << getFirstThreeDigits(values[i]) << endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using "(int)log10 + 1" is an easy way to get the number of integer digits

```
auto x = 485926;
auto len = (int)std::log10(x) + 1;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/v1jz7P